# Translation failed because of a server error on google-chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I am trying to use translate feature available in **google chrome browser**, but it says "*translation failed because of a server error*", I used retry but it didn't work, I also tried using the advanced settings  where it says "translate" and unchecked the box next to "Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language I read", but it is still not working and the page is not able to get translated from **Russian to English**.

`Page link`: http://raskalov-vit.livejournal.com/130686.html

Many thanks in advance if someone figures out why this is happening?

Comment: No idea why this is happening, but you can work around it by dropping it into the input box at http://translate.google.com/ and running it through there: [result](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fraskalov-vit.livejournal.com%2F130686.html&act=url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For reasons probably involving gremlins in the intertubes, I too have sometimes had issues where Chrome's builtin translation feature failed for no apparent reason due to a "server error". A workaround that I've found typically works is to:

1. Go to [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com)
2. Enter the URL of the page you want to translate into the box on the left side of the page.
3. If you know what language you're translating from, pick it; or, alternatively, just select "Detect Language"
4. Click on the URL in the box on the right side of the page, which will then take you to a translated version of the webpage whose URL you entered. [Like this, for example](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fraskalov-vit.livejournal.com%2F130686.html&act=url).

Comment: Sorry, but I downvoted this answer, since it only provides a workaround, with no explanation of why the feature is failing.

Answer (score -1):

Hi everybody today I manage to get my google translate woking again there has been a new update on Google chrome do download and there it is .

Hope it works for u

Comment: Can you explain how the update fixes the problem?